# Doing a sort of a loop while avoiding a certain prerequisite (beginner/python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

A beginner's problem, here it goes:

I'm writing a program which keeps records of a game of darts. The user types in the players and their respective scores. It's possible to do a query about a player's scores and ask the program for the best overall score between all the players. I have the following functions:

1. add_score
2. return_players_score
3. return_best_score
4. exit_program
5. main

In main(), we begin by creating a new empty dictionary (say, players = {}). Then we ask the user to input a number that takes him/her to the function of choice (1: add_score etc.).

Now, once we're in add_score and have added a key:value pair (player:score), we need to go back to inputting the number taking to the function of choice. I implemented it simply by writing main() to the end of add_score.

That, however, takes us to the beginning, where there's players = {} and thus whatever data we input in add_score gets wiped out. This then affects other functions and the program remains useless as long as it forgets everything right away. How to solve this?

I'd paste the actual code but it's not in English and it's an assignment anyway...

Thanks.

Comment: Even if it is not English, is it necessary to give a good answer (or ,at least, part of it)

Comment: perhaps you should define the dictionary outside of the loop, it there is one involved. Otherwise, without the code here, you're pretty much on your own..

Comment: Congratulations to everyone who did the OPs assignment for them.

Comment: Lego S, what's the problem here? I specifically left it vague enough, as testified by some of the reactions here; still had to do the work myself. Isn't one allowed to ask for help on assignment period? I wasn't the first and won't be the last to just run into a wall and need guidance, be it tiny or a bit more substantial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling `main()` from each of your other functions, you should just `return` (or run off the end of the function, which is equivalent to `return None`). Since you need the `main` function to run things repeatedly, you should use a loop.

```
def main():
    players = {}
    while True: # loop forever (until a break)
        choice = input("what do you want to do (1-4)")
        if choice == "1":
            add_score(players)
        elif choice == "2":
            return_players_score(players)
        #...
        elif choice == "4":
            break # break out of the loop to quit
        else:
            print("I didn't understand that.")
```

Comment: While I'm not totally sure I understood you, you seem to have understood me. This seems good, gotta try your way, thanks.

Comment: The python input function is the equivalent of eval(raw_input(..)) so entering 1 would give the integer 1 not "1" unless you want the users to enter the quotes.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins: Not in Python 3. In Python 3, `input()` is the equivalent of Python 2's `raw_input()` (it always returns a string).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a loop that does something like the following..

**example:**

```
while True:
    players = {}
    some code adding to players
```

This loop will always reset players to `{}`

However, if you do:

```
players = {}

while something:    
    some code adding to players
```

then `players` is not being reset at the start of each iteration through the loop

But your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this:

```
def add_score(dicccionary):
    #do something with diccionary
    main()

def main():
    dicccionary = {}
    while something:
        option = input("option")
        if option == 1:
            addscore(dicccionary)
        else:
            #otherfunction

main()
```

your *reset* problem can be solve like:

```
dicccionary = {} #global variable

def add_score():
    #do something with diccionary
    main()

def main():
    option = input("option")
    if option == 1:
        addscore()
    else:
        #otherfunction

main()
```

By the way, you shouldn't make it this way, try something as:

```
dicccionary = {} #global variable

def add_score():
    #do something with diccionary

def main():
    while somecondition:
        option = input("option")
        if option == 1:
            addscore()
        else:
            #otherfunction

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing it for real then I would go for something like:

```
import sys

class ScoreKeeper(object):
  def init(self):
    self.scores = {}

  def add_score(self, player, score):
    self.scores[player] = score

  def _print_player_score(self, player, score):
       print 'player:', player, 'score:', score

  def print_scores(self):
    for player, score in self.scores.items():
      self._print_player_score(player, score)

  def best_score(self):
    best, player = 0, "no player"
    for player, score in self.scores.items():
      if score > best:
        best, player = score, player
    self._print_player_score(player, best)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  scorer = ScoreKeeper()
  quit = lambda: sys.exit()
  choices = quit, scorer.add_score, scorer.print_scores, scorer.best_score

  def help():
    print 'Enter choice:'
    for index, c in enumerate(choices):
      print '%d) %s' % (index, c.__name__)

  def get_integer(prompt):
     res = raw_input(prompt)
     try:
       return int(res)
     except:
       print 'an integer is required'
       return get_integer(prompt)

  def get_choice():
    choice = get_integer('choice? ')
    if not 0 <= choice < len(choices):
      help()
      return get_input()
    return choice

  help()
  choice = get_choice()

  while(choice):
    args = []
    if choices[choice] == scorer.add_score:
      args.append(raw_input('player name? '))
      args.append(get_integer('score? '))
    choices[choice](*args)
    choice = get_choice()
  quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is way out of my skills at the moment. :) Doesn't even look like python to me, to be honest...